What does tabular fail to wrap long paragraph?
See the screenshot and the code below. I used tabular to create a table with specified column width. However, it fails to wrap the text. I think it is an error.

How to make sure the text is within the table, using


tabular

?
2. How to center the text in each cell in the vertical alignment?
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in,footskip=0.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathptmx, amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\linespread{1.1}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{graphicx, caption}
\captionsetup[table]{skip=0pt,singlelinecheck=off,justification=justified}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
    
    \captionof{table}{\textbf{Watchlist}} \label{tab:Stock1}
    \noindent
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{}|p{0.12\textwidth} |p{0.08\textwidth} |p{0.45\textwidth} |p{0.35\textwidth}|}
        \hline
        \textbf{Month} & \textbf{Stock} & \textbf{Initial Thesis} & \textbf{Updates and Remarks} \\
        Apr 2024 & AMZN & No. 1 online retailer, No. 1 cloud services and AI, very solid on robotics, owns a lot of data & Spends big on R\&D \\
        \hline
        Apr 2024 & META & Very strong on advertising and AI & Spends big on R\&D\\
        \hline
        Apr 2024 & LULU & Strong brand and high growth & Luxury quality, innovative fabrics. hello, hello.\\
        \hline
        
    \end{tabular*}


\end{document}


